# Testing Android apps on device

Tags: android, eclipse, testing

What is the recommended way of testing an app on a device? The emulator is slow, mostly unresponsive and a cpu beast on my machine, so I use my phone to test my app. When I make a change to code, Eclipse builds it automatically, and then I debug it on the device. Is this the most efficient way to test small changes in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has some information on testing [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/index.html).  Personally I've found that testing code is much faster on a device.  Other options without a device is to use something like Android x86 and run it in virtual environment like VirtualBox - this can be faster than the emulator.  In my opinion, to really make sure your application is working as expected (especially with graphics and memory usage) is to test with the device(s) you intend to deploy the application on.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I test my code, the emulators and on an actual device are the only ways I know of.  I usually use an actual device, but I think you can keep an emulator running to speed up time a bit, but not too much.

Answer (score 0):

It's in my opinion a good way to check the general functionality of your application. If everything works fine, I would use the emulator to check with different versions of android/screen sizes/resolutions etc. Maybe you can ask a friend who has a more powerful PC. The best possible thing is of course that friends/family/relatives etc. own Android devices so you can test your application / let it be tested on real devices.

Comment: thanks, you all. Specifically, though, for each little change I make I have to rebuild the app and then hit "debug" in Eclipse and wait for it to load on the device? There's no way to just push the new code, I assume, since the whole project has to be built each time. It takes a looong time to test over and over when I run into something I don't understand. Mainly I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a faster way.